# Understanding output of nnet function

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, multiclass-classification

I'm new with neural network so, sorry for my naive question. I would like to understand the output of nnet function. I'm using this function to perform a multiclass classification.

In particular, I have a dataset with 216 subjects, 6 variables and one column that represents the class (Classes are three).

```
   SRT_LTS_1 SRT_LTS_2 SRT_LTS_3 SRT_LTS_4 SRT_LTS_5 SRT_LTS_6 SRT_Recall_D_tot Classe
DATSANI01  1.386294  1.609438  2.079442  2.302585  2.397895  2.397895         2.564949      2
DATSANI02  1.945910  2.079442  2.079442  2.197225  2.302585  2.302585         2.079442      2
DATSANI03  2.079442  2.302585  2.302585  2.397895  2.397895  2.397895         2.397895      2
DATSANI04  1.609438  2.079442  2.397895  2.397895  2.397895  2.397895         2.397895      2
DATSANI05  2.197225  2.484907  2.484907  2.564949  2.564949  2.564949         2.484907      2
DATSANI06  2.079442  2.397895  2.484907  2.564949  2.564949  2.564949         2.564949      2
```

After splitting of dataset in training set and test test, I have modified the dataframe using `class.ind` function, to face the problem of multiclass classification, like a binary combination:

```
nnet_trainData_SRT2$Y = class.ind(nnet_trainData_SRT2$Classe)

nnet_trainData_SRT2$Classe=NULL
```

So now, my dataframe is like this:

```
SRT_LTS_1 SRT_LTS_2 SRT_LTS_3 SRT_LTS_4 SRT_LTS_5 SRT_LTS_6 SRT_Recall_D_tot Y.0 Y.1 Y.2
DATNPS_209  1.791759  2.079442  2.397895  2.564949  2.564949  2.564949         2.564949   0   1   0
DATNPS_108  2.197225  2.564949  2.564949  2.564949  2.564949  2.564949         2.564949   0   1   0
DATNPS_234  2.197225  2.397895  2.484907  2.564949  2.564949  2.564949         2.564949   0   1   0
DATNPS_191  1.609438  1.791759  2.079442  2.197225  2.302585  2.302585         1.945910   0   1   0
DATNPS_126  2.397895  2.484907  2.484907  2.564949  2.564949  2.564949         2.564949   0   1   0
DATSANI22   1.386294  1.945910  2.302585  2.484907  2.564949  2.564949         2.564949   0   0   1
```

Where 1 and 0 mean, respectively,  that subjcet is or not in one of the three class.

Then, I use nnet function:

```
model_nnSRT2<-nnet(Y~ SRT_LTS_1 +SRT_LTS_2+ SRT_LTS_3 +SRT_LTS_4+ SRT_LTS_5 +SRT_LTS_6, nnet_trainData_SRT2, size=2, decay=0.1,softmax=TRUE,entropy=TRUE).
```

But I don't understand the output of this function when I get 
`model_nnSRT2$fitted.values`:

```
                 0           1            2
    DATNPS_209 0.01699072 0.827037151 0.1559721302
    DATNPS_108 0.01789546 0.771608777 0.2104957604
    DATNPS_234 0.01645185 0.794800012 0.1887481349
    DATNPS_191 0.05037927 0.839477193 0.1101435346
    DATNPS_126 0.01603337 0.788266382 0.1957002460
    DATSANI22  0.01740139 0.836014235 0.1465843749
    DATNPS_34  0.02802254 0.791518861 0.1804586001
    DATNPS_117 0.05310552 0.835370232 0.1115242473
    DATNPS_22  0.01726448 0.799919291 0.1828162304
    DATNPS_189 0.01861498 0.775974194 0.2054108222
    DATNPS_228 0.98459076 0.014816869 0.0005923730
    DATNPS_255 0.01770538 0.788957760 0.1933368566
```

and `model_nnSRT2$residuals`.

```
                      0            1             2
DATNPS_209 -0.016990718  0.172962849 -0.1559721302
DATNPS_108 -0.017895462  0.228391223 -0.2104957604
DATNPS_234 -0.016451854  0.205199988 -0.1887481349
DATNPS_191 -0.050379272  0.160522807 -0.1101435346
DATNPS_126 -0.016033372  0.211733618 -0.1957002460
DATSANI22  -0.017401390 -0.836014235  0.8534156251
DATNPS_34  -0.028022539  0.208481139 -0.1804586001
DATNPS_117 -0.053105521  0.164629768 -0.1115242473
DATNPS_22  -0.017264479  0.200080709 -0.1828162304
DATNPS_189 -0.018614984  0.224025806 -0.2054108222
DATNPS_228  0.015409242 -0.014816869 -0.0005923730
DATNPS_255 -0.017705384  0.211042240 -0.1933368566
```

What do this continue numbers mean? Why don't i have an output in class with 0 or 1 from `model_nnSRT2$fitted.values` ? And how does this function calculate the residuals?

Comment: Not sure about the residuals, but your first output indicates the probabilities of each of your samples belonging to each class (notice that they sum up to 1 for each row).

Answer (score 1):

I've actually no experience with R in general but the output seems quite plausible from a neural net perspective.

A class in a neural network is actually a neuron which provides, depending on it's activation function, probabilities. In your case, there are three of them (`0-2`).
So, it seems like your net outputs some sort of probability per neuron (or class). You can see this by summing up the outputs. They are equal to one  per sample. This shows how good the network performs on a specific sample. For example, if your sample belongs to a specific class, the associated neuron should have an output as close as possible to one and the others to zero.

The residuals are just the difference between the predicted value and the target value. You can verify this by examining the values. So this means, that the residual has to be as small as possible. You see from your data...the residual for the miss-classified sample is really high.